# JavaScript validate date and return last available date of calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to validate my date if date not exits in calendar then return me last available date of calendar,

**Example 01**

```
Input Date    : 31-Feb-2017 
Return Result : 28-Feb-2017
```

**Example 02**

```
Input Date    : 31-March-2017
Return Result : 31-March-2017
```

**Example 03**

```
Input Date    : 31-Apr-2017
Return Result : 30-Apr-2017
```

**Example 04**

```
Input Date    : 31-Jun-2017
Return Result : 30-Jun-2017
```

**Example 05 with Leaf Year**

```
Input Date    : 31-Feb-2020 
Return Result : 29-Feb-2020
```

This is i am first trying to validate date using below function,how i can make logic for above dates.

```
function isValidDate(year, month, day) {
    var d = new Date(year, month, day);
    if (d.getFullYear() == year && d.getMonth() == month && d.getDate() == day) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And what is the issue you are facing with given code?

Comment: @Rajesh,issue is that how can i back to last available date of calendar

Comment: The algorithm would be that if it's not a valid date, return `new Date(year, month+1, 0)`, which will return the last day of *month*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Explanation as per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9):

When we call date constructor with 2 or more arguments, it tries to process using following constructor [ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.1):

```
new Date (year, month [, date [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, ms ] ] ] ] ] )
```

Here if any value that is not passed, it will be set as `NaN` and later will be parsed to `+0`. Hence timestamp is `0:0:0`

Now the trick is in a function called internally: [MakeDay](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.12).

As you see point 8, it returns

```
Day(t) + dt − 1
```

Here `Day(t)` would return number of milliseconds and date would be calculated based on `dt - 1`. Since we are passing `0`, date value would be `-1 + milliseconds` and hence it returns previous day.

Another alternate would be to create date for 1st of next month and subtract `1` as `day` or `sec`. You can select anyone based on the need,

```js
function isValidDate(year, month, day) {
  var d = new Date(year, month, day);
  return !!(d.getFullYear() == year && d.getMonth() == month && d.getDate() == day)
}

function computeLastPossibleDate(y,m,d){
  return new Date(y, m+1, 0);
}

function test(y,m,d){
  return isValidDate(y,m,d) ? new Date(y,m,d) : computeLastPossibleDate(y,m,d)
}

// 31st Feb.
console.log(test(2017, 1, 31).toString())
// 31st March
console.log(test(2017, 2, 31).toString())
// 31st April
console.log(test(2017, 3, 31).toString())
// 50th Dec.
console.log(test(2017, 11, 50).toString())
```

**Note:** If there is anything missing, please share it as a comment with your vote. Just vote without comment will not help anyone.

Comment: Not my downvote, but a good answer should include an explanation of how it fixes the OP's issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I was going to delete after you added an answer, but I'm suspecting revenge votes and hence keeping it. I'll try to add explanation and make sure it add something more to your explanation. :-)

Comment: @RobG I have tried to explain. Hope its not redundancy of your explanation. Also please point out any inconsistencies. I'm not sure of `Day(t)` but I guess it would yield `1/msPerDay`. Thanks :-)

Comment: Seems fine. Note that the current spec is [*ECMAScript 2016*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-makeday), soon to be replaced by [*ECMAScript 2017*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) (which is a draft, even though it doesn't say so). ;-)

Comment: @RobG i assumed it will not change much specially internal processing as it would be backward compatible. Would still check for any difference and would update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The last day of the month is given by the zero day of the following month, so:

```js
function getDate(year, month, day) {
    var d = new Date(year, month, day);
    if (d.getMonth() == month) {
        return d;
    }
    return new Date(year, +month + 1, 0);
}

console.log(getDate(2017,1,29).toString());
console.log(getDate(2017,0,32).toString());
```

BTW, to test for a valid date you only need to test the month since if the month is larger than months in a year, it will affect both month and year. If the day is greater than the number of days in the month it will affect the month too. Nothing affects the year (unless you pass a year less than 100, in which case it's treated as 1900 + year).

Comment: this will become invalid when Month is January, see the answer should be Jan 31 2017 not Feb 28 2017

Comment: @KapilaPerera—no, it doesn't. The OP is calling the date constructor directly so `getDate(2017,1,29)` is for 29 Feb which should return 28 Feb.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isValidDate(year, month, day) {
    var d = new Date(year, month, day);
    if (d.getFullYear() == year && d.getMonth() == month && d.getDate() == day) {
        return d;
    }
    else
        rturn new Date(year, month, 0);;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  function isValidDate(year, month, day) {
    if(month<=12){

        var temp_day=day;
        var d = new Date(year, month, day);
        var lastDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(),0);
        var getlastday=lastDay.getDate();
        if(getlastday<=day){
            //var date=(d.getDate())+"/"+(d.getMonth())+"/"+(d.getFullYear());
            var date=(getlastday)+"-"+(month)+"-"+(lastDay.getFullYear());
            return date;
        }else{
            //var date=(lastDay.getDate())+"-"+(lastDay.getMonth())+"-"+(lastDay.getFullYear());
            var date=(day)+"/"+(month)+"/"+(year);
            return date;
        }
    }
    else{
        return "month not valid";
    }
}
```

try this code