# Google sheets timezone

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so, I have this google sheets from where, I need to generate some PDF, it's working fine, except the date. if **I have selected the date as 29/12/2021 in my sheet, it appears as 28/12/2021 in the generated PDF**. I don't what went wrong, I have tried changing the locale and time zone. but nothing came out as well. what's exactly the problem? and I wanted to know that, is there any way I can change this using apps-script?

Comment: Are you aware that there is a time zone setting for the script and the spreadsheet?

Comment: In your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66194990

Comment: @Tanaike ... where can I find the timezone in app script ? Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: @Mike Steelson About your question of `where can I find the timezone in app script ?`, how about checking the manifest file `appsscript.json`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests) When you see `appsscript.json`, you can see the current timezone by the property of `timeZone`. When the new IDE was released, this value had a bug. But this bug had been removed in April 2021. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175718931) If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Many Thx @Tanaike ... I really enjoy reading your posts and you write English very well, much better that I do (I am French).

Comment: @MikeSteelson App Script's time zone can be checked/changed by using the `Legacy editor` and clicking `File > Project properties > Time Zone` from the menu above the script editor.

Comment: @Mike Steelson Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1):

The best and simpliest way is to use `.getDisplayValue()` instead of `.getValue()`

[getDisplayValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)